# HTML table columns width: mixing px, % and auto width for text

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with some columns with fixed width and others with *auto* to accomodate longer texts. This is the main CSS:

```css
/* Table size */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}

/* Column sizes */
thead th:nth-child(1) { width: 60px; }  /* Serial. */
thead th:nth-child(2) { width: auto; }  /* Customer/country */
thead th:nth-child(3) { width: auto; }  /* Product */
thead th:nth-child(4) { width: 70px; }  /* Operator */
thead th:nth-child(5) { width: 80px; }  /* Status */
thead th:nth-child(6) { width: 20px; }  /* Checkmark */
thead th:nth-child(7) { width: 50px; }  /* Compl. */
thead th:nth-child(8) { width: auto; }  /* Notes */
```

And here's the JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xn2cwp4u/

The problem with this setup, visible from the example, is that when using large widescreen monitors the rightmost column takes too much width then the other 2 with the *auto* width, due to the text inside.

[image: Width of the rightmost column]

I would like to have the three columns with violet header (2, 3 & 8) to take the remaining space but distributed according to a percentage, for example 30%, 15% and 55%. So something like this:

```css
/* Column sizes */
thead th:nth-child(1) { width: 60px; } /* Serial. */
thead th:nth-child(2) { width: 30%; }  /* Customer/country <-- */
thead th:nth-child(3) { width: 15%; }  /* Product <-- */
thead th:nth-child(4) { width: 70px; } /* Operator */
thead th:nth-child(5) { width: 80px; } /* Status */
thead th:nth-child(6) { width: 20px; } /* Checkmark */
thead th:nth-child(7) { width: 50px; } /* Compl. */
thead th:nth-child(8) { width: 55%; }  /* Notes <-- */
```

But I cannot mix pixels with %, unless I enable `table-layout: fixed` on the table:

https://jsfiddle.net/xn2cwp4u/1/

This works but when doing that I cannot auto-adapt the minimum width of the *Product* column to the text inside the cells anymore. It's overflowing when the window width is not enough, while before with the *auto* width the column grew to make a single line of text!

[image: Overflowing text when using table-layout: fixed]

I don't want to set `overflow: hidden;` because this clips the text, I want the column width to be at least enough to display it (as it did with *auto*).

So, how can I use pixels and % while also adapting the width of some columns (*Product* in my case) to accomodate the text in a single line (in the CSS I'm using `white-space: nowrap;` on that column)? Is it possible?

EDIT:
To further clarify, from the total available table width:

1. Subtract the fixed width columns (1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
2. Subtract the necessary width to fit the text on column 3 (the column with `white-space: nowrap;`) to avoid overflowing
3. Redistribute the (eventual) remaining space according to the percentages (30% to column 2, 15% to column 3 and 55% to column 8)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. At one point you say that that 3rd column should take up 15% of the remaining space (the space it shares with the remaining other columns which have no fixed width) and then (I think but may have misinterpreted) you are saying that the 3rd column should be as wide as it needs to be for all the text in it to show on one line (no word wrapping). Could you clarify, thanks.

Comment: did you try like 
{
  width:15%;
 min-width: 100px /* as example */
}

Comment: @AHaworth What I want, if possible, is first make the 3rd column as wide as it needs to contain the text and **then** redistribute the eventual remaining space using the percentages. Say that there're 100 free pixels, I would like 30px more on column 2, 15px more on column 3 and 55px more on column 8.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution (https://jsfiddle.net/fmq0rv4w/):

```
/* Column sizes */
thead th:nth-child(1) { width: 60px; } /* Serial. */
thead th:nth-child(2) { width: auto; } /* Customer/country */
thead th:nth-child(3) { width: auto; } /* Product */
thead th:nth-child(4) { width: 70px; } /* Operator */
thead th:nth-child(5) { width: 80px; } /* Status */
thead th:nth-child(6) { width: 20px; } /* Checkmark */
thead th:nth-child(7) { width: 50px; } /* Compl. */
thead th:nth-child(8) { width: auto; } /* Notes */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  thead th:nth-child(1) { width: 10%; } /* Serial. */
  thead th:nth-child(2) { width: 13.3%; } /* Customer/country */
  thead th:nth-child(3) { width: 13.3%; } /* Product */
  thead th:nth-child(4) { width: 11.7%; } /* Operator */
  thead th:nth-child(5) { width: 13.3%; } /* Status */
  thead th:nth-child(6) { width: 3.3%; } /* Checkmark */
  thead th:nth-child(7) { width: 8.3%; } /* Compl. */
  thead th:nth-child(8) { width: 26.7%; } /* Notes */
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  thead th:nth-child(1) { width: 5%; } /* Serial. */
  thead th:nth-child(2) { width: 19.2%; } /* Customer/country */
  thead th:nth-child(3) { width: 19.2%; } /* Product */
  thead th:nth-child(4) { width: 5.8%; } /* Operator */
  thead th:nth-child(5) { width: 6.7%; } /* Status */
  thead th:nth-child(6) { width: 1.7%; } /* Checkmark */
  thead th:nth-child(7) { width: 4.2%; } /* Compl. */
  thead th:nth-child(8) { width: 38.3%; } /* Notes */
}
```

I maintain your first approach for mobile version and create multiple CSS media queries to distribute the columns width in different browser widths. It's not something lineal (some columns fixed size and the other with percentages) but you can emulate it adding more media queries.

I have created only 2 media queries and the result is good. When the browser becomes wider, you get more or less the sizes what you expect. You haven't the blue columns with fixed size but with the % that you assign to them in the media queries you ensure that their widths are always almost the same.

And your product column it's not a problem. If need more space, it takes more space but the others columns have an relative expected %. However, if you want, you can try this style for this column:

```
/* Keep text on the same line */
tbody td:nth-child(3) {
    /* These are technically the same, but use both */
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
    word-break: break-all;
    /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
    word-break: break-word;
    /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

The text can break in multiple lines even when not have white spaces. I use that for columns with emails, that are difficult to break in multiple lines.

Comment: Having percentages only it fits quite well, but unfortunately it also changes the width of the columns that I don't like to change (such as _checkmark_ #6). I would like those columns to be **fixed width** so this doesn't properly answer the question.